# How to supress repeated items from an array but keeping the order?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Lets say we have an array of `n` numbers: `a = [4,8,2,7,7]`, so i need the the "same array", but with no repeated items, so one idea would be, take the `a[n-1]` and make a comparison with the `a[n-2]`, *if* `a[n-2]` = `a[n-1]`, then `a[n-2]` += 1, and repeat this process `n-1` times until get the array with no repeated items, but *in general* if `a[n]` > `a[n+1]` the resulted array must keep this order, idem if  `a[n]` < `a[n+1]`.
But there is a problem with this, what about if the array was `a = [6,6,2,8,7]`, the last comparison would result `a = [7,6,2,8,7]` and now `a[0] = a[n-1]`.

There is a better option to do this? Ideas?

Comment: Unless you know something about the values (like that they're always this small), you can't do this in linear time, which is what you're trying to do. Either you go for a very naive approach that scales poorly (for every element in the array, check if it's equal to any element of the resulting array; if not, append it)(takes quadratic time and constant space), or keep a sorting structure while you're filtering the array (takes `O(n log n)` time, but `O(n)` space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straightforward O(n log n)-time algorithm. Prepare a list `p = [0,...,n-1]` and sort it stably by indexing into `a` to determine the results of the comparisons, e.g., for `a = [4,8,2,7,7]`, the sorted list is `p = [2,0,3,4,1]`, and for `a = [6,6,2,8,7]`, the sorted list is `p = [2,0,1,4,3]`. Compute the inverse permutation, i.e., define another array `q` such that `q[p[i]] = i` for all `i = 0,...,n-1`. Iterate `i = 1,...,n-1`, setting `a[q[i]] = max(a[q[i]], a[q[i-1]]+1)`.

Comment: This seems more complicated to explain than just keeping a heap sort structure of used values while you're iteratively building the result.